# Frequently updating UICollectionView's data leads to laggy scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, uicollectionview, combine

I have a UICollectionView that updates its data about every 1 second. An incoming websocket event triggers the update. When I scroll down the collection view I clearly note a lag every time the update happens.

The stack is:

- Combine Publishers for sending data
- UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout for UI
- UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource as UICollectionView's data source
- One ViewModel instance per cell that hold the data

E.g. one of the cell's update handlers look like this:

```
viewModel.titleSubject
   .sink { [weak self] title in
                guard let _ = self?.dataSource?.snapshot().indexOfSection(0) else { return }
                let itemIDs = self?.dataSource?.snapshot().itemIdentifiers(inSection: 0)
                if let header = itemIDs?.first as? HeaderCellViewModel {
                    guard header.text != title else { return }
                    header.text = title
                    if var snapshot = self?.dataSource?.snapshot() {
                        snapshot.reloadItems([header])
                        self?.dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
                    }
                }
            }
   .store(in: &cancelBag)
```

I trigger the subject without doing any Thread/Queue work myself:

```
titleSubject.send("Hey, I'm a new title")
```

How could I improve the update stack, so I don't get laggy scrolling?

Comment: This is very common issue in list views, update only specific cell.

Comment: What do you use in snapshot, are you create snapshot means thumbnail of images ?

Comment: if you are calling `reloadItems` on your collection view, you are shooting yourself in the foot.  that is a very slow operation that causes a lot of view invalidation, redrawing, and and re-layout calculations.  You should not do that.

Comment: @Naresh This code only updates a single cell via updating the content of a ViewModel attached to one cell

Comment: @ScottThompson Please note that the `reloadItems` method of `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` here is not the `reloadItems` method of `UICollectionView`

Comment: Why are you applying the snapshot every time the title in any of the cells changes, cant you observe an array of item ID's and apply when on those change? When applying a snapshot I assume there is some calculation going under the hood...

Comment: Apple's promise on applying snapshots: only the diff will be rerendered, it's the ultimate motivation of the diffable APIs (hence its name)

Comment: @SimeonRumy I don't. The titleSubject emits an new value and I apply it to one item ID only which is of type HeaderCellViewModel